# exit from loop if condition meets in eclipse rcptt

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcptt

I want to exit from a loop if condition meets in eclipse rcptt.

I am using the below code:

```
proc "wait-until" [val iconName] {
    loop [val count 1] [val n 5] {
        if [$count | lt $n] {

            try{

                let [val text [get-button "Configure" | get-property "getToolTipText()" -raw]] {
                    if [$text | contains $iconName] {

                        recur [$count | plus 100] [$n]
                    }
                }
            } -catch {
                show-alert "inside catch"
            }

            recur [$count | plus 1] [$n]
        } -else {
        }
    }
}
```

but it continues if try condition meets also.

where i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Loops in RCPTT are weird because they don't simply iterate, they rather "dig in", like recursion would do.

The keyword 'recur' is meant to express this.

In your case, if the try{} runs successfully at the (n)-th time, it will still have to "climb out" and execute the code parts after the 'recur' instruction (n-1) times.

You should re-structure your code to have 'recur' as the last instruction in your loop, if possible.

Comment: if [$text | contains $iconName]  is working because i check the value using show-alert command.
But it does not break if the condition meets. Can u give me an example how to break from rcptt loop or how i can wait until a specific element is loaded .

Comment: not clear to me. can u please give me an example how i stop loop execution. No need to use my example. You can help me by just providing an example.

Comment: You stop a loop by not calling 'recur'. If you want to jump out from the stack, then cause an exception. I.e.: get-window "Foo". Stop thinking of loops as a loop, instead imagine them as a function which can be invoked by writing 'recur'.

Comment: well ... upvote for the time you have given actually. Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Well, i came up with a solution like below:

```
proc "wait-for-button" [val name] {
  loop [val count 0] {
  try {
      get-button $name
      } -catch {
              if [eq $count 300] { // 30 seconds
                  throw-error [concat "wait-for-button: Could not find button " $name]
              }
              wait 100
             recur [$count | plus 1]
     }//catch ends
  }//loop ends
}//proc -ends
```

What it does actually, it will iterate for 300 times. If it founds a button in try, it will stop execution.
If not, it will go to catch block and do the next recursion again.

Comment: Maybe, you can spare that loop by adding '-times 300 -delay 100' parameters to your try{} command.

Comment: @AdamHorvath can you please help me related this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271324/use-ecl-command-as-proc-parameter-input