# use ecl command as proc parameter input

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcptt

I am facing an issue about passing ecl command as procedure input.

I have an ecl command:

```
get-editor [format "Configuration Editor - %s" $projNmae] | click
```

I want to take this ecl command as parameter input in a procedure. 
What i am doing is:

```
proc "wait-until-element-is-loaded" [val editor] {

loop [val count 0] {
    try {

        $editor | click

    } -catch {
        if [eq $count 4] {
            // 30 seconds
            throw-error [concat "element can not be loaded within the wait time. " $editor]
        }
        wait 100
        recur [$count | plus 1]
    }
 }
}
```

Then calling the procedure like:

```
wait-until-element-is-loaded |  get-editor [format "Configuration Editor - %s" $projName]
```

or

```
wait-until-element-is-loaded -editor  get-editor [format "Configuration Editor - %s" $projName]
```

But its not working. I want to do this as i want to pass different parameter at different times while executing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you pass a Widget to a user-written procedure.

I remember trying it once, and it didn't work for me too.

Convert your `wait-until-element-is-loaded` to receive a string and call `get-editor` inside it.